# React testing library - testing setState inside Promise then caused An update to TestComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a custom hook which setting a state in a Promise then/catch block.

This is my custom hook:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import {useBackendApi} from './backend-api';

export function useMyCustomHook(): {status?: Status; loadData: () => void} {
    const [status, setStatus] = useState<Status>();
    const backendApi = useBackendApi();

    const loadData = (): void => {
        backendApi.makeApiCall().then(() => {
            setStatus(Status.SUCCESS);
        }).catch(() => {
            setStatus(Status.ERROR);
        });
    };

    return {status, loadData};
}

export enum Status {
    SUCCESS = 1,
    ERROR = 2,
}
```

And these are my tests:

```
import {act, renderHook, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import * as BackendApiHooks from './backend-api';
import {Status, useMyCustomHook} from './my-custom-hook';

describe('useMyCustomHook', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('should set the status to SUCCESS when makeApiCall resolved', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(BackendApiHooks, 'useBackendApi').mockReturnValue({
            makeApiCall: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()),
        });
        const {result} = renderHook(() => useMyCustomHook());

        await act(() => {
            result.current.loadData();
        });

        await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.status).toBe(Status.SUCCESS));
    });

    it('should set the status to ERROR when makeApiCall rejected', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(BackendApiHooks, 'useBackendApi').mockReturnValue({
            makeApiCall: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.reject()),
        });
        const {result} = renderHook(() => useMyCustomHook());

        await act(() => {
            result.current.loadData();
        });

        await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.status).toBe(Status.ERROR));
    });
});
```

My tests are passed but on the first test there is an error printed to the console:

```
Warning: An update to TestComponent inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

act(() => {
  /* fire events that update state */
});
/* assert on the output */

This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
    at TestComponent (/****/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:281:5)

   8 |     const loadData = (): void => {
   9 |         backendApi.makeApiCall().then(() => {
> 10 |             setStatus(Status.SUCCESS);
     |             ^
  11 |         }).catch(() => {
  12 |             setStatus(Status.ERROR);
  13 |         });

  at printWarning (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:86:30)
  at error (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:60:7)
  at warnIfUpdatesNotWrappedWithActDEV (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27589:9)
  at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25508:5)
  at dispatchSetState (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17527:7)
  at src/modules/table/components/my-custom-hook.ts:10:13
```

It happens although I wrapped the `result.current.loadData()` in `act`.

- Important note: It happens only on the first test (with the resolve mock) but not on the second test (with the reject mock)

Couldn't find any relevant solution in other questions. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried [`await waitForNextUpdate()`](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/usage/advanced-hooks#async)?

Comment: @morganney `waitForNextUpdate` is not returned from `renderHook` in the latest `@testing-library/react` version.